# Why not all Firestore's document changes are seen by the application?

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I have 20 documents in the cloud.

Within a loop, I update those 20 documents one after the other with a update data transaction for each. I don't care about the order of the returned modified document.

```
myDocs.forEach {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
        Firestore.firestore().runTransaction({ (trans, errorPointer) -> Any? in
            trans.updateData(/* 3x fields are updated for this document */)
            ...
            return
        }, completion: { (object, error) in
           ...
        })
    }
}
```

For some reason, I can't see the `modified` document type change for all of them.

```
snapshot.documentChanges.forEach { diff in

    if (diff.type == .added) {
        print("Added: \(diff.document.data())")
    }

    if (diff.type == .modified) {
        print("Modified: \(diff.document.data())")
    }
}
```

Though, even if I can't see all the modified documents, the end result is all my documents are updated in the application.

```
if let documents = querySnapshot?.documents {
    // can see all changes here
}
```

Here what I see and the quantity of `modified` documents received is not always the same. Some time, I receive ALL the `modified` documents, but it is rare.

- Starting the app, I get 20x `added` documents that I can see from `snapshot.documentChanges.forEach`
- It executes the loop described above that execute one update transaction per document.
- A snapshot is received and one document is tagged as `modified`, but in total, half of the documents were updated in that snapshot.
- A snapshot is received and two documents is tagged as `modified`, but in total, the rest of documents were update in that snapshot
- It would be ok if all 20x documents would be received with a `modified` type associated with it, but it is not the case.

Is it possible my application is not responsive enough that it misses changes?

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong to have that kind of issue?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem: if your listener stays active, you should be getting a `.modified` for each **document** that was modified (so that existed already). --- You may not get a `.modified` for each update, i.e. if you update the same document repeatedly, listeners may only get the final state of those updates. But you definitely should be getting the final, current state for each modified document. Is that not happening for you? Can you show more on the behavior you get, i.e. by logging the offending value.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, I updated my question and added a section of what I see. Let me know if it helps (or not) to understand what is going on. By the way, if a second mobile device execute the same thing, I should also see the 20 documents modified on my mobile device and it is not the case.

Comment: "Though, even if I can't see all the modified documents, the end result is all my documents are updated in the application." This really sounds like the SDK and server are working as expected, and the problem is either in your code or in your understanding of what they're supposed to do. Note in my first comment the distinction between an update and an updates document. You are guaranteed to get all updated documents, but you may not get every intermediate update. --- To troubleshoot the problem further, we'll need to see the code and its output that shows that you're not getting all documents

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, based on your comment, I think I found the guilty code. Long time ago, we introduced a throttling for each snapshot received and was not expecting that would cause the issue. I will do more test to make sure it is only that code that causing the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My issue was caused by the throttling mechanism that we added around the Firestore snapshot.

After fixing the issue for that throttling, I started to see all the documents' changes.